# RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException on Dynamic call

Tags: c#, dynamic, roslyn

I'm getting an unexpected RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException when passing an object as a dynamic argument.

I'll try to explain the scenario,  as it's too involved to paste code easily.
I'm doing some really weird hackery with Roslyn,  so it's going to sound odd.

1. Execute application
2. Monitor source code for changes
3. Recompile what is effectively a diff of the assembly with the changed files/classes
4. Load the new compiled assembly into the original AppDomain
5. Pass existing object instances to the new/changed code as Dynamic, so the new code can operate on existing context/application state.

This dynamic passing ***should*** work, because the type is compatible:  i.e., in my case I can guarantee it has functionally matching methods/types.

But when I go to execute the changed+reloaded method,  and it receives an object of type dynamic,  I'm getting this exception.

```
RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException was unhandled.
An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation
```

Per MSDN:

> Exceptions of this kind differ from RuntimeBinderException in that
>   RuntimeBinderException represents a failure to bind in the sense of a
>   usual compiler error, whereas RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException
>   represents a malfunctioning of the runtime binder itself.

Google has absolutely no results for this.   I don't know how to debug further into it either.   Any suggestions?

( I did do some sandbox testing to assure myself that I could load different assemblies at runtime into a test application and pass instanced types from different assemblies to a single method accepting a dynamic parameter.  So it does work in that scenario. )

Comment: I'm afraid that without actual code, we won't be able to help you. Could you simplify your code as much as possible, but so that it still shows the error and post it here? And in any case, it looks like a bug in `dynamic`, so you might want to post it to [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: Yes, this looks like an actual bug in the Runtime binder and if you can, you should try to create a minimal repro and post it on Connect. Unfortunately I don't think we'll be able to fix it in the near future, so you'll have to find a workaround.

Comment: I've been trying to put together a reasonably simple repro case,  but I haven't been able to easily narrow it down yet.  I'll give it another shot though.

Comment: Any news about this problem? I am facing a similar situation.

Comment: Nope, still stands.  I basically dropped my project because I couldn't find a workaround, and it's a low priority bug.

Comment: The new assembly that you're compiling, does it have the same name as the original assembly? If you load a newer version of an assembly into an AppDomain where that assembly has been loaded already it will give you a type from the assembly loaded first and ignore the new version

Comment: No, I was timestamping the assembly names.  This was an entirely different problem.

Comment: what do you exactly do on the number 5? create a simple code example for just that step.

Comment: Not an easy thing to do, as #5 is the additive culmination of all the previous steps.  Also, it was an experiment that I dropped a year ago and don't plan on resuming.

Comment: Hi. I'm interested in anything that causes `RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException` (so I can make it not cause that). It looks like in this case you may have been in a situation where you would have two different types with the same full assembly-qualified name in the same expression, which is a case I already know about, but if it's not could you provide a repro?

Comment: I dropped the project 5 years ago, but you might be able to reproduce it if you follow the general steps I outlined.  The concept was to create a hot-reloading system in C#.  The test case was simple IIRC,  just a class with Add, Subtract, Mult or some such methods.

Comment: Yep. It was one I've already fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer the question without more details, but reading what you've said, there are a few things to note:

1. Internally, all type names are fully qualified. This means that the compiler will reject your code if you try to treat two types as the same unless they are from the same assembly, with the same namespace and name. Getting slightly different types to mesh in .Net is tricky.
2. `dynamic` doesn't always work as you might intuitively think. If you're playing with the compiler, it's very much worth learning how IL works, and looking at both your code and the base-class-library code to see how they interact.

A very useful tool for low-level .Net work is ILSpy: http://ilspy.net/